# Express block/allow some nested endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My application has a guest mode. I want to block access to endpoints that need signing in.

Lets say I have the following snippet:

```js
app.use('/api/user', authRoutes);

// profile route
router.get('/:userId', viewAction); // <- visits profile, allowed for guests
router.get('/:userId/follow', followAction); // <- follow profile, not allowed for guests
```

Now I could just check inside followAction if the user is a guest or not, but I want to do it the other way around. So I want to block all routes except for ones which have specified they allow guests. (so I don't accidentally forget to check for auth)

I was thinking of something like an array of allowed endpoints for a guest, but this doesn't work since the 'dynamic' endpoints won't match.

`const guestEndpoints = ['/user/i_cant_just_put_a_userId_here']; // <- missing :userId here.`

Is it possible to do something like this?

`router.get('/:userId', viewAction, allowedForGuests);`

I think this should be quite easy to do, am I missing something?

Comment: this is possible `router.get('/:userId', viewAction, allowedForGuests, function(req, res))` where `viewAction` and `allowedForGuests` are router middlewares that get mounted for that specific endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into a 'jwt' library and adding a middleware for those specific protected routes. JWT (json web token) works by sending the client a token when they log in that is then cached on the client side and requiring that token to be sent with each request to access protected routes. The token is usually set in the headers.

Here is a good article to get started on middleware...

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

And here is the jwt npm module that I prefer...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Comment: I already have JWT in use, I know when a user is a guest or authenticated. I'm just looking for the blocking.

Comment: Then I would recommend a middleware to check whatever variable indicates the users status and either pass them to the route or send a unauthorized status back in the response.. That link should help you get started with middleware.